# Yeast washed, combine containers?

Tags: reusing-yeast, yeast-cultures

We washed yeast from our last beer and now it's sitting in multiple containers in the fridge. The mixture is mostly water with some yeast at the bottom. Is it acceptable practice to combine the yeast in one container and have the area left filled with the water?

Answer (score 2):

If you practice good sanitation.

Decant the water off and combine to save space.